# How to create a type convertable validation attribute in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, validation, attributes

I want to create a custom attribute for validation control if a type is convertable to other?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class TypeParsableAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    private readonly string _displayName;
    private readonly Type _type;

    public TypeParsableAttribute(Type type, string displayName = "")
    {
        _displayName = displayName;
        _type = type;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var name = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_displayName) ? _displayName : validationContext.DisplayName;

        bool isParsable = // how to chech parsable object to _type ???

        return !isParsable
            ? new ValidationResult(FormatErrorMessage(name))
            : ValidationResult.Success;
    }
    
}
```

and I wan to use this for any property. Validate

```
public class Myclass
{
    [TypeParsable(typeof(int))]
    public string Name {get; set;}

    [TypeParsable(typeof(Datetime))]
    public string BirthDate {get; set;}

    [TypeParsable(typeof(int))]
    public float Salary {get; set;}
}
```

I want to get validation results for this type of properties, but I could not generate code for check if convertable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Convert.ChangeType(), Check the sample code

```
string x="10x";
Type tt = 30.GetType();
bool canConvert = false;
try{
    object obj= Convert.ChangeType(x,tt);
    canConvert = true;
}
catch(Exception ex){
    canConvert = false;
}

Console.WriteLine(canConvert);
```

Some Reference Links below

[link 1](https://makolyte.com/csharp-use-convert-changetype-to-convert-string-to-any-type/)

[MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

Use `TypeDescriptor`. Read details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typedescriptor.getconverter?view=net-5.0#System_ComponentModel_TypeDescriptor_GetConverter_System_Object_).

`bool isParsable = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(_type).IsValid(value);`

`GetConverter` gets the built-in converter for a specified type and `IsValid` validates whether the given value object is valid for this type. Check `IsValid` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.typeconverter.isvalid?view=net-5.0)

Comment: TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(typeof(int)).IsValid(12) returns false why?